# Is there a way to get Sum of column whose datatype is varchar

Tags: sql-server

**Is there a way in SQL to get Sum of column whose datatype is varchar. I tried with Cast method in SQL but it doesn't work. If any body has an idea kindly share with me.**

Query I tried:

```
select cast(sum(Total) as int) from tbl_preorder where emailid='xyz@email.com'
```

Comment: You can use convert key word : http://stackoverflow.com/a/18333443/2218635

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

```
select sum(convert(decimal(10,2), Total)) from tbl_preorder 
       where emailid='xyz@email.com'
```

Comment: Thanks your answer is diffrent.

Comment: In case you have decimals in your numbers, I suggest you use thie answer as converting your numbers to integers won't work.

Answer (score 2):

Try this :

```
select sum(cast(total as int)) from tbl_preorder where emailid='xyz@email.com'
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT SUM(CAST(Total AS int)) FROM tbl_preorder WHERE emailid='xyz@email.com'
```

Answer (score 1):

This must work:

```
select sum(cast(Total as integer)) from tbl_preorder where emailid='xyz@email.com'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this simple way

```
select SUM(Cast CONVERT(INT,total)) from tbl_preorder where emailid='xyz@email.com'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following query to solve the issue

```
 select sum(cast(Total as unsigned)) from tbl_preorder where emailid='xyz@email.com';
```

You need to use the UNSIGNED [INTEGER] for the solution to work.